# TSQL - SQL Server mumber of the week in Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using the query below to get the number of the week in a month:

```
datepart(day, datediff(day, 0,TABLE.DATE), 102))/7 * 7)/7 + 1
```

Now I need to change the script that if a week ends in the next month, it should show `1` instead of `5`.

Does anybody can help me?

Comment: Statement is broken. `102` is from hidden conversion part I guess.

Comment: @Premi, what are you upto? Can you show us your complete query?

Comment: Give sample data please.

Comment: As @IvanStarostin says, your SQL query is broken. Where's your `convert( ..., ..., 102)` part to this? It doesn't look like the conversion is even needed if all you are extracting is the week of a month.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Modulo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) by 4, you can get the month number `1` instead of `5`.

For an example I tested with the 5th week and it result as `1`:

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS DATETIME = '2016-07-29 10:00:00';
SELECT CASE ((DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @TestDate)) /7 * 7) /7 + 1) % 4
       WHEN 0 THEN 4 
       ELSE ((DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @TestDate)) /7 * 7) /7 + 1) % 4 END
```

In your query, you wrongly used [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms174420.aspx). Actually it requires 2 parameters only.

Comment: @Premi Could you confirm whether the answer is working for you or not. Based on the feedback we can add/update more clarification.